# How can I implement the traffic(+drawing) functionality in the game?

Tags: unity

I am a beginner game developer. Games such as "Cities: Skyline", "Simcity", "Citybounds", and "Traffic lanes 3" directly build roads and show simulations of cars moving over them. I have no knowledge to make these things. I can use Unity, construct2. How can I express things like roads, lanes, intersections, snapping, traffic simulations, path finding, driver AI,  traffic lights, even wheels on the road?

[image]
Road drawing

[image]
Traffic simulating

Comment: Each one of these things: "roads, lanes, intersections, snapping, traffic simulations, path finding, driver AI, traffic lights, even wheels" should be a separate question. A solution to snapping won't give you a solution to traffic simulation, after all. So please choose just one topic to focus on first. You can always post a second question later to ask about the next bit of your roadway feature set that you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation part is probably the easieast. Every point where two or more roads connect should become a node in a graph, the roads connecting them are the edges. A simple pathfinding algorithm can navigate a car from one point to another.

Lanes are just a modification on this. Make the same road represent multiple edges, one per lane. If the car needs to be in a certain lane to e.g. turn left, it will use the corresponding edge.

Drawing these roads is very complicated, especially when they start intersecting. The roads can be done using bezier curves if they need to bend, but the intersections have to be procedurally generated somehow.

If you're just starting game developement, especially if you have no programming knowledge, I'd start with something smaller. There's a reason these games aren't produced by indies too often.